# (C++) std::ios::fail vs std::cin.failbit

Tags: c++

I am reading about the iostream operations in C++, and came across [failbit](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/).
When I use `std::cin.std::ios::fail()`, I get `0`, which is expected if there were no problems.

However, when I try to directly access the local variable of `std::cin` called `failbit`, I seem to get `4` in the output. Why is that? Are `std::cin.std::ios::fail()` and `std::cin.failbit` different things? I am pretty sure I'm missing something.

---

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::cout << std::cin.std::ios::fail() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::cin.failbit << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
4
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: [`failbit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) is a static variable in ythe stream base class [`std::ios_base`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base).

Comment: i suggest you this reference instead: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate. It is sometimes harder to read, but often more complete and correct

Comment: Before I was interrupted by the youngest kid, `failbit` is a *bit* flag available through [`rdstate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdstate). It affects the result of the [`fail`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) function from the child-class [`std::basic_ios`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail).